# Why define-values is not bound in a Racket macro with #lang racket/base?

Tags: macros, racket

I am trying to learn how to write Macros in Racket.
I've gone through the excellent [Fear of Macros](http://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/Transform_.html) tutorial and am now trying to experiment with the basic ideas.

So I defined `my-if` slightly differently from what was shown in the tutorial, and I am getting an error `define-values: unbound identifier;` in:

```
#lang racket/base

(define-syntax (my-if stx)
  (define-values (_ condition yes no)
    (apply values (syntax->list stx)))
  (datum->syntax stx `(if ,condition ,yes ,no)))
```

If I use `#lang racket` instead of `racket/base` it works.

Looking up the definition of `define-values` in the Manual, it seems to be part of `racket/base`!

```
define-values  provided from racket/base, racket
```

So why is Racket complaining about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `(require (for-syntax racket/base))` to import `racket/base` also at phase 1 (compile time). Using `#lang racket/base` provides `define-values` only at phase 0 (runtime).

Comment: I hadn't thought of that because the tutorial mentioned that `And at compile time, only racket/base is required for you automatically—not the full racket`... I guess I misundertood what that means.

Comment: @renato The tutorial has a note in the margin in section 3.1. 

Truth be told it can be a bit confusing in the beginning. In section 3.4 Greg explains that `#lang racket` requires `racket/base` at compile time. However `#lang racket/base` doesn't do the same (which is a very natural thing to assume).